# what is Package in oracle and what is syntax for that

Tags: oracle

Can anyone in simple way say me what is the **Package**, and how this is useful . And what is the syntax To create A **Package** . Because i am using first time Oracle .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages provide a method of encapsulating related procedures, functions, and associated cursors and variables together as a unit in the database.

For more help, you can just check out [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch14.htm#packhead).

Comment: can you say me where i can see all the document for oracle how can i use when i am using .NET

Comment: just check out this link - It has all the related oracle docs + the cook book for ORACLE+.NET .. 
http://www.oracle.com/pls/db111/homepage